# Pandas multi-level index to rows

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to transform this DataFrame:

```
>>> df
D1     D2  
S1 S2  S1 S2
0  -4  1  -6
1  -5  2  -7
3  -8  3  -9
```

to something like:

```
>>> df
    0    1    2    3
D1  -4   -5   NaN  -8
D2  NaN  -6   -7   -9
```

Essentially the values in columns `(D1,S1)` and `(D2,S1)` need to be merged into column names and the values in columns `(D1,S2)` and `(D2,S2)` become the only data values.

How could I achieve that simply and efficiently ?

Answer (score 3):

The desired DataFrame have the `D`s in the index. `stack` moves column level values into the index. So it is natural to think about calling `stack`:

```
In [43]: result = df.stack(level=0); result
Out[43]: 
      S1  S2
0 D1   0  -4
  D2   1  -6
1 D1   1  -5
  D2   2  -7
2 D1   3  -8
  D2   3  -9
```

The desired DataFrame only has `D`s in the index, so let's drop the outer level values:

```
In [44]: result.index = result.index.droplevel(0); result
Out[44]: 
    S1  S2
D1   0  -4
D2   1  -6
D1   1  -5
D2   2  -7
D1   3  -8
D2   3  -9
```

We now want the `S1` column to become a column level value. That can be done by first moving the `S1` column into the index,

```
In [45]: result = result.set_index('S1', append=True); result
Out[45]: 
       S2
   S1    
D1 0   -4
D2 1   -6
D1 1   -5
D2 2   -7
D1 3   -8
D2 3   -9
```

and then calling `unstack` to move the index level to a column level:

```
In [46]: result = result.unstack('S1'); result
Out[46]: 
    S2          
S1   0  1   2  3
D1  -4 -5 NaN -8
D2 NaN -6  -7 -9
```

---

Putting it all together,

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({('D1', 'S1'): [0, 1, 3],
 ('D1', 'S2'): [-4, -5, -8],
 ('D2', 'S1'): [1, 2, 3],
 ('D2', 'S2'): [-6, -7, -9]})

result = df.stack(level=0)
result.index = result.index.droplevel(0)
result = result.set_index('S1', append=True)
result = result.unstack('S1')
result.columns = result.columns.droplevel(0)
print(result)
```

yields

```
S1   0  1   2  3
D1  -4 -5 NaN -8
D2 NaN -6  -7 -9
```

---

For reference: The four fundamental DataFrame reshaping operations are

- [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html),
- [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html),
- [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and
- [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html).

They are fundamental because a DataFrame is just an array with index and column
levels. These operators allow you to move values from the array to index levels
to column levels and back. Combining of these 4 operations in various ways can
solve a lot of DataFrame reshaping problems.